# Virtual Debugging with VMWare in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, vmware

I can't find any help on this topic that isn't from 8+ years ago and/or from a much older version of VMWare. I installed VMWare Workstation 16 Pro and I already had Visual Studio Community 2019 installed on Windows 10 Pro. I read that I should find new tools in Visual Studio for virtual debugging but I didn't find anything new in there. I didn't see anything about a Visual Studio plugin when installing VMWare either. Can anyone help?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VMware_Workstation), this feature was removed starting with workstation version 12 (Don't know why!!).
[image]
As an alternative, you can install [Microsoft Remote debugging tools](https://my.visualstudio.com/Downloads?q=remote%20tools%20visual%20studio%202019) on the desired VMWare Machine and configure it (refer to [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-csharp?view=vs-2022)), after that, go to Visual studio --> Project Settings --> debug --> Check the box "Use Remote Machine" and enter machine name or IP Address.
[image]
PS: You need to set a password for the user account on the VMWare Machine.